# web.config oldsite to newsite 301, domain/root to new page AND old pages to oldpages

Tags: redirect, web-config, root, wildcard-mapping

In my web.config file I want to be able to accomplish both redirects below:

Redirect the root/domain:
oldsite.org  to newsite.org/this-is-thenewsite

AND
page wildcard redirects:
oldsite.org/any-all-oldpage to newsite.org/any-all-oldpage

What would be the proper way to accomplish both?

I currently redirect all old traffic to the new page  And I know I can use {R0} or {R1} to wildcard the pages.

I just dont know the best way to do both   TIA!

Comment: I guess the question can be better distilled down to Ho to detect when the user comes to just the olddomain and when the user has a file in the URI
oldsite.org vs oldsite.org/filename

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect one domain to another with a rule similar to this:

```xml
<rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^oldsite.org$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://newsite.org/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Source: [Web.config redirects with rewrite rules - https, www, and more](https://blog.elmah.io/web-config-redirects-with-rewrite-rules-https-www-and-more/)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently using the following two match statements get me what I need.:

```
<match url=".+" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" />
```

looks for just the domain in the URI

```
<match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
```

looks at any files in the URI